# bootstrap modal stay open when the js validation is being executed and form action is redirected if it is true

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code that execute the submit event from the form and I want the modal stay open if the validation is false, ***but it doesn't work***.

```
    var myForm = document.updteform;
    var condition = true;
    if(myForm.pass1.value !== myForm.pass.value){
        alert("Password Doesn't Match, Please try again."); 
        myForm.pass1.focus();
        condition = false; //it will return the value
    }
```

After that... this code below will execute.

```
if(!condition) {
        if(evt.preventDefault) { event.preventDefault(); }    
        else if(evt.returnValue) { evt.returnValue = false; }    
        else { return false; }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for editing R. Garcia :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works...

**Step 1**: create an onlick that calls the function to your **JavaScript**

**Step 2**: create a function:

```
    function changePass(){

                  var oldpass = document.getElementById("password1").value; 
                  var newpass = document.getElementById("password2").value; 

      if (oldpass != newpass) {
      alert("Password Doesn't Match Please try again.");
      return false; //the modal will not close because it doesn't return a value.
      } else {
              document.getElementById("form_id").action = "<?= base_url('index.php/Employee/updateUser'); ?>"; // Setting form action to your Controller page.
              document.getElementById("form_id").submit(); // Submitting form
      }
```

}

That say so.. Hopefully it'll help :)